# Si el select tiene valor "Negro" ocultar input

Tags: javascript, html

> Si el select-option tiene valor "Negro" ocultar el input (que tiene name="color").

HTML:

```
<form method="POST">

     <select name="opcion">
        <option>Negro</option>
        <option>Color</option>
     </select>

     <input name="color" type="text"></input>

<button type="submit">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var opcion = document.getElementsByName("opcion");
    var color = document.getElementsByName("color");

    valor = opcion[0].innerHTML;
    if (valor == "Negro"){
        color[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para este caso te haré los siguientes comentarios:

- Lo ideal sería que manejes la obtención del texto elegido del `option` por medio del evento `change` ya que si tienes N elementos entonces se haría tedioso estar indicando el índice del valor deseado
- En lugar de tratar de recuperar para ocultar un `input` por su `name` el cual puede ser un atributo presente con el mismo valor en **N** `inputs` y que de nuevo tendrías que mostrar el índice del elemento a modificar mejor asignale un id lo cual lo hace un elemento único
- Por otro lado para ocultar el elemento te puedes auxiliar de `display` y de los valores `none` y de inline; donde el primero sería para que no se muestre y el segundo es para mostrarlo

**Propuesta**

```html
    <form method="POST">
    
         <select id="opciones" name="opcion">
            <option>---</option>
            <option>Negro</option>
            <option>Color</option>
         </select>
    
         <input id="color" name="color" type="text"></input>
    
    <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
    </form>
    
    <script>
      let opciones  = document.getElementById("opciones")
      let cajaTexto = document.getElementById("color")
      
      opciones.addEventListener("change", () => {
        let eleccion = opciones.options[opciones.selectedIndex].text
        
        if(eleccion === "Negro") {
          cajaTexto.style.display = "none"
        } else {
          cajaTexto.style.display = "inline"
        }
      })
    </script>
```

Usamos `inline` para que la caja de texto siga apareciendo en línea con el botón de guardar, es decir en el mismo renglón.

> Sería mejor ocupar `display` en lugar de `visibility` por que el primero remueve el elemento del flujo del DOM y haría que el botón se mueva a lado del `SELECT` mientras que el `visibility` si lo quita de la vista del usuario pero hace que su espacio ocupado se *respete* y al no existir re acomodos se ve *raro* que quede el `select` + un espacio en blanco + `botón de guardar`

**Lecturas recomendadas**

- [atributo id](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id)
- [evento change](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)
- [propiedad display](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/display)